# 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'Play' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've tried a lot but I can't seem to get another particle in, the last 3 variables are for particles, but it won't let me do the last one. I need help, please

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunScript: MonoBehaviour
{
   public float damage;
   public float range;

   public Camera fpsCamera;
   public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
   public GameObject impactEffect;
   public GameObject bulletEffect
    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        bulletThing.Play();

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCamera.transform.position, fpsCamera.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
            GameObject impactGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            Destroy(impactGO, 2f);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new so I just google stuff and if that doesn't work I ask questions!

Comment: 'GameObjet' doesn't have 'play' method are you trying to play 'animation'? 'animator'? what are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to add a particle

Comment: yeah but you are trying to play of 'GameObject', i mean 'bulletEffect' variable. so if you want to try to play ParticleSystem that attached 'bulletEffect', you should try bulletEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play()

Comment: Your code has both a bulletEffect and bulletThing items. Are they the same? And if so, what are they? If bulletEffect is a particle, then define bulletEffect as a ParticleSystem, not a GameObject as you have

Comment: yeah if 'bulletEffect' is 'GameObject' that attached ParticleSystem, than you can do that as you said. Because 'GameObject' doesn't have 'Play' method so errors is obvious

Comment: What is `bulletThing`? It doesn't exist in your class ...